# Extract data from an array and include it to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have a javascript object as follows.

```
{
  name: "tom",
  age: 5,
  fruits: [
    {name: "apple",qty: 4},
    {name: "orange",qty: 13},
    {name: "banana",qty: 3}
  ]
}
```

I am trying to convert this object into an object given below.

```
{
  name: "tom",
  age: 5,
  apple: 4,
  orange: 13,
  banana: 3
}
```

How do I achieve this? I have tried to loop through the fruits array but I am unable to find a way to create a variable with the fruit name and assign the qty to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach` and `delete` to clean up the old key. Take care not to overwrite keys accidentally, though (you could test `if (e.name in obj)` as a safety check).

```js
const obj = {
  name: "tom",
  age: 5,
  fruits: [
    {name: "apple",qty: 4},
    {name: "orange",qty: 13},
    {name: "banana",qty: 3}
  ]
};

obj.fruits.forEach(e => obj[e.name] = e.qty);
delete obj.fruits;

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below simple code

```
  var b={
  name: "tom",
  age: 5}

  for (var i = 0; i<a.fruits.length; i++) {
     b[a.fruits[i].name]=a.fruits[i].qty;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This a generic function to convert if you don't want to mutate the original object. [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object to get `fruits` and `rest` of the properties separately. Then you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to to create a new object.

```js
let obj = {
  name: "tom",
  age: 5,
  fruits: [
    {name: "apple",qty: 4},
    {name: "orange",qty: 13},
    {name: "banana",qty: 3}
  ]
}

const converter = ({ fruits, ...rest }) => 
                    Object.assign(rest, ...fruits.map(({ name, qty }) => ({ [name]: qty })))

console.log(converter(obj))
```